# MVC3 - File upload controller / handler not receiving the image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
File uploader plugin to do ajax image upload and i see the request in fiddler go through, with the image in it when i pick a local image. The fiddler request has the PNG file in it.

From fiddler -

```
POST http://localhost:16169/client/account/uploadimage/202?qqfile=logo_l.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:16169
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-File-Name: logo_l.png
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Referer: http://localhost:16169/client/events/edit/202
Content-Length: 32660
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

�PNG

���
IHDR�����������¯�C���gAMA����
�a���   pHYs�����&�?���tEXtSoftware�Microsoft Office�5q��IDATx^��G�=���8,����@p
�ݓ�@�$��������.+��T���H���ϗ}��<��ܹsgg�O�����6111A���A2�@J�%�K!��K��)����ζ)�Mm��@�{�;ˤ�
ˤt�d���FK���og�Ц�6�a �=�eR�?�eR:m2�@J�%�F���m
hS@��0�����2)��2)�6b �ђa����6�)�MvHv�og���Oa��N�1��hɰ���l���&;$����L����LJ�M�Hi�d�h�v�Mm
```

I have truncated the request but you get the idea that the image is being transmitted in the post body.

But when i do

```
var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```

in the controller that handles this post request. Image comes out to be null, Looking at the debugger all other values are present.

```
Request.Files.Count = 0
```

as well.

Anyone gone through this, or can help me debug this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution..

```
 WebImage image = new WebImage(Request.InputStream);
```

instead of -

```
var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```