# WebImage.GetImageFromRequest returns null when file is present

Tags: c#, html, razor, input, upload

My `WebImage.GetImageFromRequest` returns null, even when there is a file. How can this be?

The cshtml code:

```
@{
    if(IsPost)
    {
        if(Request["upload"] != null)
        {
            image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
            if(image != null)
            {
                // something
            }
        }

        if(Request["btn"] != null)
        {
            // something
        }
    }
}
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    Upload image:
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="img" />
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="update" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add `enctype` attribute to your `form` tag as this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: After full research I found correct cause of problem but I don't remove other answers because maybe useful in some other problems of users.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this alternative method instead(because of some bugs):

```
public static WebImage GetImageFromRequest() {
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

if (request.Files.Length == 0) {
    return null;
}

try {
    var postedFile = request.Files[0];
    var image = new WebImage(postedFile.InputStream) {
        FileName = postedFile.FileName
    };
    return image;
} catch {
    // The user uploaded a file that wasn't an image or an image format that we don't understand
    return null;
}
}
```

from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1682158.aspx/1)

Comment: How would I send the request to this method when its null? Think im just a bit too confused at this point, can you try clarify an implementation to my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
image = new WebImage(Request.InputStream);
```

instead of:

```
image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7577698/2040375)

Comment: When using this it return a new error from the line "An image could not be constructed from the content provided."

Comment: This answer maybe not work properly for old versions of .NET!